# 'ArgumentError: invalid base64' when decoding tokens with devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, bearer-token, devise-token-auth

I'm using gems `devise_token_auth' and` graphql_devise` for my authentication and I'm able to generate the token. Here is an example one that I just generated along with client and expiry:

```
#<struct DeviseTokenAuth::TokenFactory::Token
 client="TeoomlVVA0xMCNKff4Q3Fw",
 token="DOXnJR8iPlwHgXHUYJXi6w",
 token_hash="$2a$10$PdliAqqiGXyp1ARfTQzYEeQMKxSF7X1peXgyDLRBz44cKXlI1zh1W",
```

Then when I'm trying to authenticate with it, it can't decode the token raising `ArgumentError: invalid base64` from inside of the devise_token_auth gem from `set_user_by_token` method that calls `decode_bearer_token`. The method receives my token and on this line returns {}: `JSON.parse(Base64.strict_decode64(encoded_token)) rescue {}`. The token is present but when I run just  `Base64.strict_decode64(encoded_token)` from `` from <internal:pack>:29:in `unpack1' ``, it raises an error `ArgumentError: invalid base64`.

I'm using Rails version: 7.0.4.3
Ruby version: ruby 3.2.2

The token itself is generated during login in the same gem in `user.rb` in `create_token` in this line: `token = DeviseTokenAuth::TokenFactory.create(client: client, lifespan: lifespan, cost: cost)` with all args being `nil`. The token is returned and later this output returned to the front end via the rest of pipeline of `devise_token_auth` and `graphql_devise`:

```
tokens[token.client] = {
        token:  token.token_hash,
        expiry: token.expiry
      }.merge!(token_extras)
```

Even at this time, the token can't be decoded if I try to call `Base64.strict_decode64(encoded_token)` on it.